# Do all Macbooks have a Thunderbolt port?

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, hdmi, thunderbolt-display

I'm helping out with organizing a local conference, and I want all the speakers to be able to plug in their computers. While most laptops have an HDMI port, it's notably absent from a lot of Macbook models.

I'm wondering: If I guarantee that there's a Thunderbolt-to-HDMI adapter in every room, will that cover all Macbooks? Or are there Macbooks that don't have a Thunderbolt port?

Answer (score 3):

Even MacBook Pro have different adapter ports and needs. The new MacBook only has USB-C. All MacBook Pro have some form of thunderbolt but not the same connectors.

AirPlay might be the most common way to get video out, so consider that an an AppleTV if you can't be sure which adapters are needed.

These articles explain and have great photos:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207443
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201736

Newer Models have Thunderbolt 3 which is also called USB-C

[image]

This website has good cables/adapters for very good price.

https://www.monoprice.com/search/index?keyword=Apple%20&v_Product_Type_uFilter=Apple%20Cables

Comment: Yes, you will need both Mini Display-Port (also works with Thunderbolt 2) and USB-C (also works with Thunderbolt 3) adaptors to have all the bases covered.

Comment: Woah - great answer. I've added Airplay and a second article